# Hide desktop icons (c++)(SHGetSetSetting)

Tags: c++, windows

I'm  trying to make a program who use [SHGetSetSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetsetsettings) to hide desktop icons (Windows10). But my code return me -1 when I change the value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ShlObj_core.h>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

void HideDesktopIcons() {
    SHELLSTATE shellstate;
    ZeroMemory(&shellstate, sizeof(shellstate));
    shellstate.fHideIcons=TRUE;
    shellstate.fShowExtensions = TRUE; //I change also extensions for test
    SHGetSetSettings(&shellstate, SSF_HIDEICONS|SSF_SHOWEXTENSIONS,TRUE);

    SHELLFLAGSTATE shellflagState;
    SHGetSettings(&shellflagState, SSF_HIDEICONS);
    cout << shellflagState.fHideIcons <<endl;
}

int main()
{
    HideDesktopIcons();
}
```

Consol return "-1" and icons are still there. . . 
need your light. thx

Comment: You should check the return values of both `SHGetSetSettings` and `SHGetSettings` to make sure they worked.

Comment: You got energy i give you + .

Comment: `SSF_HIDEICONS` doesn't work in Windows 10. It updates the relevant Registry setting only, but doesn't update the Shell to match